# gzip huge file(~30G) in PHP

Tags: php

does any of you have some experience with compressing huge file in PHP using "gzcompress" ?
more efficient is compress the same file in a shell using tar ?
To be more exact : 
such huge file is gzipped directly in PHP. PHP script is running via cron job everyday.
My intuition tells me this is slower than executing tar directly in a system shell.
But this is still my intuition only :) Question is if it's slower ? If yes than how big the differences can be ? Differences especially when we are talking about execution time.

Comment: Wouldn't call that a job for PHP. I'd recommend `system('gzip -1c myfile > myfile.gz');` or simply `system('gzip -1 myfile');`

Comment: Do you have a system with 20+gigs of ram? Remember that gzcompress works IN MEMORY, so you'd need to be able to buffer the resulting gzip data. In worst case scenarios, gzip can actually increase the data's size and you'd need more than 30gig to hold it.

Comment: why such a large file? Is this a one time thing or is this a on going problem?

Comment: I found such stuff in one of the systems (I did not create it). I just was surprised. File is gzipped directly in PHP. Machine has 12G of RAM PHP memory limit is set to -1 (unlimited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem like a PHP web job to me. Is this getting gzipped on demand for delivery or transfer? I would put that sort of thing in a queue for processing by a cron job in the shell.

Comment: it's a daily routine running as cronjob.

Comment: You're definitely going to be better off using gzip uncompressed.txt > compressed.txt.gz.

Answer (score 1):

PHP isn't going to be any faster than tar + gzip, and will be much more taxing on your web serving process.  I'd redesign the application to add the gzip request to a queue (database, filesystem, whatever), return immediately with "your request is in the works...", and meta refresh the page every N seconds until another process (cron job) has done the work, then return a download link to the completed binary.

Comment: I would do that in the same way. Question is if such solution (gziping directly in PHP) is slower ? if it is about how big differences we are talking about ?